# Stuffy Doll blocking 11/11 trampler. Phyrexian Obliterator blocks 11/11 trampler

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What my problem is when last night a [Stuffy Doll](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stuffy%20Doll) blocked my 11/11 trampler, the result was me taking 11 damage and Stuffy Doll absorbing one of that damage from the defending player who took ten damage. We called mtg for a ruling and that was the one given. How is it that Stuffy Doll takes 11 damage, but at the same time ten of it gets through to opponent? I was expecting to take one damage from Stuffy Doll, seeing as how Stuffy Doll only really took one. I don't understand that in one case Stuffy Doll has taken one and in the other Stuffy Doll has taken 11. Sounds like a logical fallacy ie 1 = 11.

Second question is what if I block an 11/11 trampler with a [Phyrexian Obliterator](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Phyrexian%20Obliterator) ? Will the opponent have to sacrifice 5 permanents or 11 permanents?  Would it be any different if the attacking creature didn't have trample?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should have only taken 1 damage.  When damage happens, you choose how to assign your 11 damage. You must assign at least 1 to Stuffy Doll. Because your creature has trample, you can assign the other 10 to your opponent. Even though Stuffy Doll has indestructible, 1 damage is still considered lethal damage. So Stuffy Doll will take 1 damage, your opponent will take 10, and Stuffy Doll will deal you 1 damage.

Similar thing for your other question. Your opponent must assign at least 5 damage to your obliterator. He can assign as much as 11. So how many permanents he sacrifices depends on how much he chooses to assign. If his creature does not have trample, he must assign all 11 to the obliterator, and he will sacrifice 11 permanents.

Comment: 100% correct. *702.19b The controller of an attacking creature with trample first assigns damage to the creature(s) blocking it. Once all those blocking creatures are assigned lethal damage, any **remaining** damage is assigned as its controller chooses among those blocking creatures and the player or planeswalker the creature is attacking.*

Comment: Thank you so much Gendolkari and ikegami.  That makes sense and is exactly what I figured.  In the past I raised the question of 11 powered creature blocking an Obliterator and he said I would only have to sac 5 permanents because that is all the creature could take.  I figured he was wrong.  You guys are awesome for clearing this up for me.  You would think I know how to play this game with ten years of experience but there are some technical fine points that always need to be cleared up here and there in order to really get your fundamentals cemented in stone.  Thanks again.  Arthur.